How do I handle browser back button event in Lightning Web Components on a Salesforce Site?
I have tried below approaches but they didn't worked. After applying below solutions when I clicked on back button it gets clicked but not performing anything.

Please check this:- https://sfdc.danielzeidler.com/2019/12/19/integrating-the-browsers-back-and-forward-buttons-in-a-lightning-web-component/
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256636/how-do-i-handle-caching-for-browser-back-button-in-lwc
